# Computing Bayes Factors for pairwise comparisons, linear mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size, lsmeans, bayes-factors

A reviewer asked for either Bayes Factors or effect sizes for pairwise, planned comparisons in linear mixed modeling. In the experimental design, I have 30 participants, one fixed factor (repeated measures) with three conditions (Consistency). Passage & Subject are random effects. In response to the reviewer, I have computed Cohen's D for each pairwise comparison (see output below). Because reporting effect sizes when doing mixed modeling is controversial, I want to consider reporting Bayes Factors instead (which I have never done before). After doing some research, I have tried to find the Bayes Factor for each comparison by inputting the t-value and sample size.

A couple of questions on computing Bayes Factors: First, can I compute a Bayes Factor from a t-value and sample size for mixed models? And second, what sample size would I use? In the study, I collected data on 30 participants. But my output gives me different n-sizes across each group.

Here is my code for the overall analysis with Cohen's D and contrasts:

```r
PdatFIN$RT_target <- as.numeric(PdatFIN$RT_target)
PdatFIN$Consistency <- as.factor(PdatFIN$Consistency)
str(PdatFIN)
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage), 
          PdatFIN); summary(m); Anova(m)
lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
pairs(m.contrasts)
```

Here is my output:

```r
group: 1
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 148 1709.04 527.09   1631 1697.14 650.12 846 2974  2128 0.22    -1.06 43.33
group: 2
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 162 2137.73 741.01 2056.5 2081.52 717.58 897 4414  3517 0.70     0.34 58.22
group: 3
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 166 1888.73 736.85   1740 1811.35 708.68 750 4318  3568 1.01     0.83 57.19

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage)
   Data: PdatFIN

REML criterion at convergence: 7314.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0682 -0.6320 -0.1771  0.5346  4.1376 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 203923   451.6   
 Passage  (Intercept)  23091   152.0   
 Residual             239054   488.9   
Number of obs: 476, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 18

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1711.58      98.75  17.333
Consistency2   427.71      56.19   7.612
Consistency3   173.18      55.99   3.093

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Cnsst2
Consistncy2 -0.301       
Consistncy3 -0.303  0.532
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Consistency 59.216  2  1.385e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #Cohens d
> lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
                    t       df         d
Consistency2 7.612028 432.5373 0.7320127
Consistency3 3.092820 434.6247 0.2967068
> m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
> pairs(m.contrasts)
 contrast                    estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Consistency1 - Consistency2     -428 56.2 432  -7.607  <.0001
 Consistency1 - Consistency3     -173 56.1 434  -3.090  0.0060
 Consistency2 - Consistency3      255 54.3 429   4.688  <.0001

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Here's the code I used to compute the Bayes Factors for two contrasts & the resulting Bayes Factors (Note I inputted 30 for n; I'm not sure if that's appropriate):

```r
result <- ttest.tstat(t = 7.61, n1 = 30)
exp(result[['bf']])
[1] 627304.5

result <- ttest.tstat(t = 3.09, n1 = 30)
exp(result[['bf']])
[1] 9.106463
```

I inputted 30 for n to get the Bayes Factor because the experiment was based on 30 participants. However, note that n = 148 for Group 1, n = 162 for Group 2 and n = 166 for Group 3. So, my guess is I did not use the appropriate n size. If not, what n value should I use. Do I add a second n value? I thought adding a second n indicated an independent groups design. Or, did I go about getting Bayes Factors the wrong way? Help, please ...

If the Bayes Factors and my understanding is correct, then the comparison for Consistency2 (Group 1 & Group 2; t-value of 7.61) and comparison for Consistency3 (Group 1 & Group 3, t-value of 3.09) means that the data is 627304 x and 9.106 x more likely to occur under the alternative hypothesis than the null hypothesis?

Again, as always, many thanks to all of you who have helped me on my journey to computing and understanding mixed modeling. My progress seems slow but your support/feedback has been immensely helpful.

Comment: I know this question stems from a reviewer request but does it really make sense to compute BayesFactor for contrasts obtained with `lmer`? Wouldn't it be better to do the full Bayesian analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the input but as you know, I'm trying to satisfy a reviewer's request.

Comment: (+1) Great description of your situation! It's ok to argue with reviewers. Perhaps you can acknowledge their point and then make a principled case for one or the other of the approaches. At this point, neither is ideal, but effect sizes seem more in line with your current analytic approach than Bayes factors.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Unfortunately, two of three reviewers asked for effect sizes, so I'm uncertain how easily I can convince the action editor that I shouldn't report them. I am leaning toward reporting Cohen's d.